# Why isn't prod level updated after applying SP - SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My environment is `SQL Exp 2012 | SELECT @@VERSION = 11.0.2100.6 (RTM)`

I then installed SP4 + GDR with no errors.

Now, `SELECT @@VERSION = 11.0.2100.6 (RTM)`.  I would have expected `11.0.7462.6`.

Discovery report:

[image: Discovery report]

In registry:

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Microsoft>Microsoft SQL Server>
> 110>SQLServer2012>CurrentVersion>PatchLevel=11.4.7462.6 & Version=11.4.7462.6
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE>Microsoft>Microsoft SQL Server>
> ADK>MSSQLServer>CurrentVersion=11.0.2100.6
> ```

If I attempt to patch with SP4 + GDR (based upon shown version = `11.0.2100.`6) the Shared Features in unchecked and I get the error

> There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be
>   updated on this computer.

Using the GUI to update:

[image: Error]

It appears to already be patched, which it is.

On another express instance, I followed the above process and the version was `11.0.7462.6` after the SP + GDR update. Great?

**My question:**

Why isn't the version not getting updated to the patch level?  How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since it is Express, do you need to use a [different patch](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56042)? (I honestly don't know, never patched Express)

Comment: Triple-check that you're running `SELECT @@VERSION` against the right computer and against the right instance.

Comment: Express uses the same patch as non-Exp versions.  I did triple-check that I am on the right server, right instance when using @@VERSION.